# Trying to get a email script working with Google Forms

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get forms to email certain cells to a specified email.  I have gotten it to email the cells, but it won't email the new rows it just keeps emailing the first row to the email can someone help me with the code so it will email the newly added row and columns I need

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 100; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 100);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = 'coryabaird@gmail.com'; // First column
    var message = row[27]; // Second column
    var subject = row[3];
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the script?

Answer (score 1):

Okay here's that tutorial example with an EmailSent column and a couple other changes.  What else would you like?

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow=2; 
  var dataRange=sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data=dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var row=data[i];
    var emailAddress='coryabaird@gmail.com'; // First column
    var message=row[27]; // Second column
    var emailSent=row[?]; // fourth column
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    if(emailSent!='Sent' && MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()>0) {
       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
       sheet.getRange(i+sr,4).setValue('Sent');
    }else{
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('emailSent: ' + emailSent + ', Quota: ' + MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota());
    }
  }
}
```

Image:

[image]